# When I add margin top for the container, the header will follow

Tags: html, css

I am new to HTML and CSS, I have a problem. When I add `margin-top` to `<div id="parent-container">` the header will follow. Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DCtH7/1/

Need help still learning. Thank you in advance.

One thing, how to make the header on top of the div? When i scroll down the div covers the header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not because the `margin-top`, It's because you've set `position: fixed` to your header so add `top:0` to make your header positioned to the top of the page.

[Fixed Header](http://jsfiddle.net/DCtH7/3/)

Comment: thanks but one thing, how to make the header on top of the div? when i  scroll down the div covers the header.

Comment: sir when i add height to my div it covers the header

Answer (score 0):

It's not because the `margin-top` property of your `#parent-container`.

It's because you've set `position: fixed` to your header. Remove it and you should be fine.

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DCtH7/2/)**

Comment: thanks, but when i add height to div and when i scroll down it covers the header. how to send it to the back?

Answer (score 0):

Updated CSS:-

## parent-container {

width: 100px;
height: 600px;
background-color: black;
margin: 0 auto;
top: 100px;
position:relative;
}